# CSS 'outline' property in IE, and jQuery errors

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm getting an error in jQuery core when I try the following code in IE8;

```
 $("input:focus").addClass("focused").animate(
            {outlineWidth:"4px",outlineColor:"#8bc0e8"},200);
```

I have tested the code on other PC's with the exact same version of IE, same OS (Windows 7), but rather confusingly the error only occurs on certain PC's and not others.

Has anyone experienced problems using outline in jQuery?

I've separated into single properties, e.g. outlineWidth and outlineColor etc, but get the same error.

Comment: Under no circumstances tell us *what* error you are getting exactly! It would take away all the fun of guessing. :)

Comment: What error are you getting?  Do these certain PCs have javascript turned off?

Comment: Hmmm, OK if it helps. "b is undefined" in line 1522. Not much help though really!

Comment: Did you declare a DOCTYPE? IE8 requires you to specify a DOCTYPE to use the outline-width property.

Comment: Javascript is enabled. The systems are exactly the same in nearly every respect. I'm thinking maybe though it could be something to do with security and the system caret. I think system caret and outline may be the same thing ... possibly?

Comment: Thanks jqueryrocks. I do have a doctype (xhtml 1.0 transitional), and have now tried with others which unfortunately makes no difference. But you're right - no doctype, no outline

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever I see "IE8" and "it works on one PC but not on another, with identical OS and IE version", my first thought is that one of them is probably rendering it in IE7-combatibility mode.

To find out if this is the case, open IE's Developer Tools window -- it shows the rendering mode at the top right.

This would also make sense, since IE8 does support the `outline` style, whereas IE7 doesn't. If IE8 is in compatibity mode, it won't support it.

Comment: Spudley - thanks a million. I still have to have a nasty solution in place, but at least now I know the reason why. I will personally check every PC in the QA department and set to IE8 compatibility mode.

Comment: @BusterLuke: there is a `<meta`> tag you can use to force IE to go into the right rendering mode. It's called `X-UA-Compatible`. See here for more: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288325%28v=vs.85%29.aspx (lots more info also here on SO and from Google)

Comment: Thanks again Spudley. This is very useful stuff