# how to make html button dotted inline appear

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to add javascript to set Focus on a button, and hope to make the button look just the way it does when a user 'tabs' thru the HTML Form to reach the button.

The page that I am working on has an button element:
`<input type="Submit" id="myBtn" class="myBtnClass >`

In javascript function, I set focus to it using:
`$("#myBtn").focus()`  When this function is invoked, I can see change of button image. Also, when I click 'Enter', the form does get submitted.  However, in this case, when the image changes, I don't see the "Dotted inline" that generally appears on buttons.

but the dotted line Does appear when a user "tabs" to that button.

Am I expected to do anything other than `$("#myBtn").focus()`" ?

Comment: Nope, works fine for me. The button displays focus: http://jsfiddle.net/ZaDpt/5/

Comment: I should've mentioned, this is an IE8 problem only for me. The dotted outline shows up all the time in Firefox, but only intermittently / sporadically on IE8.

Comment: As you stated it is likely to be browser related. Chain a CSS method to your blur method to set the outline to dashed.

Comment: Looks like "outline" is not the right word. I was talking about the dotted line that appears ON the buttons.. somewhat inside the border.

Comment: using javascript to add pseudo classes is the wrong way to go about it, but either way, sounds like you are confusing :active with :focus.  chain :active to your :focus statement

Answer (score 0):

you can use css property:

```
`outline`
```

Comment: This totally misses the point that there's an IE8 bug  he's dealing with.

Answer (score 0):

Could be running in IE7 compatibility mode, or using the wrong doctype.
See this similar question for more info and possible solutions: [CSS 'outline' property in IE, and jQuery errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6073292/css-outline-property-in-ie-and-jquery-errors)

Comment: I am in regular IE8 mode. Not compatibility.  I wonder... if I can simulate a user pressing "tab" key